# How to install cloud-torrent on Heroku correctly

Tags: go, heroku, heroku-cli

So, I'm trying to deploy [cloud-torrent](https://github.com/ananthtcr/cloud-torrent) repository to heroku as its doc said "Click this button to Deploy this to heroku" OK,I redirected to heroku dashboard and deploying started, but nothing happend on my web app ...

i tried `heroku run bash` in git bash but when i type `cloud-torrent --help` it says:

> cloud-torrent: command not found

Has anyone successfully installed this package on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the last time that repo was maintained was on Apr 9, 2016
So I doubt it works with all the updates to go and on heroku.
You can try this
[Heroku build app](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/karl-chan/google-drive-torrent)

This might not work on the go as well.
I have a working repo. Let me know if you need it.